# SQL Server 2014 - XQuery - get comma-separated List

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery-sql

I have a database table in SQL Server 2014 with only an `ID` column (`int`) and a column `xmldata` of type `XML`.

This `xmldata` column contains for example:

```
<book>
    <title>a nice Novel</title>
    <author>Maria</author>
    <author>Peter</author>
</book>
```

As expected, I have multiple books, therefore multiple rows with `xmldata`.

I now want to execute a query for all books, where Peter is an Author. I tried this in some xPath2.0 testers and got to the conclusion that:

```
/book/author/concat(text(), if(position() != last())then ',' else '')
```

works.

If you try to port this success into SQL Server 2014 Express it looks like this, which is correctly escaped syntax etc.:

```
SELECT id
FROM books
WHERE 'Peter' IN (xmldata.query('/book/author/concat(text(), if(position() != last())then '','' else '''')'))
```

SQL Server however does not seem to support a construction like `/concat(...)` because of:

> The XQuery syntax '/function()' is not supported.

I am at a loss then however, why `/text()` would work in:

```
SELECT id, xmldata.query('/book/author/text()') 
FROM books
```

which it does.

My constraints:

- I am bound to use SQL Server
- I am bound to xpath or something else that can be "injected" as the statement above (if the structure of the xml or the database changes, the xpath above could be changed isolated and the application logic above that constructs the `Where` clause will not be touched) **SEE EDIT**

Is there a way to make this work?

regards,

BillDoor

**EDIT:**

**My second constraint boils down to this:**

An Application constructs the Where clause by

```
expression <operator> value(s)
```

expression is stored in a database and is mapped by the xmlTag eg.:

```
   | tokenname|  querystring
   | "author" | "xmldata.query(/book/author/text())"
```

the values are presented by the Requesting user. so if the user asks for the author "Peter" with operator "EQUALS" the application constructs:

```
xmaldata.query(/book/author/text()) = "Peter"
```

as where clause.

If the customer now decides that author needs to be nested in an `<authors>` element, i can simply change the expression in the construction-database and the whole machine keeps running without any changes to code, simply manageable.

So i need a way to achieve that

```
<xPath> <operator> "Peter"
```

**or any other combination of this three isolated components** (see above: `"Peter" IN <xPath>...`) gets me all of Peters' books, even if there are multiple unsorted authors.

This would not suffice either (its not sqlserver syntax, but you get the idea):

```
WHERE xmldata.exist('/dossier/client[text() = "$1"]', "Peter") = 1;
```

because the operator is still nested in the expression, i could not request `<> "Peter"`.

I know this is strange, please don't question the concept as a whole - it has a history :/

EDIT: further clarification:

The filter-rules come into the app in an XML structure basically:

- Operator: "EQ"
- field: "name"
- value "Peter"

evaluates to:

- expression =  `lookupExpressionForField("name")` --> "table2.xmldata.value('book/author/name[1]', 'varchar')"
- operator = `lookUpOperatorMapping("EQ")` --> "="
- value = `FormatValues("Peter")` --> "Peter" (if multiple values are passed FormatValues cosntructs a comma seperated list)

the application then builds:
 - `constructClause(String expression,String operator,String value)`

"table2.xmldata.value('book/author/name[1]', 'varchar')" + "=" + "Peter"

then constructs a Select statement with the result as WHERE clause.

it does not build it like this, unescaped, unfiltered for injection etc, but this is the basic idea.

i can influence how the input is Transalted, meaning I can implement the methods:

- `lookupExpressionForField(String field)`
- `lookUpOperatorMapping(String operator)`
- `Formatvalues(List<String> values)` | `Formatvalues(String value)`
- `constructClause(String expression,String operator,String value)`

however i choose to do, i can change the parameter types, I can freely implement them. The less the better of course. So simply constructing a comma-seperated list with xPath would be optimal (like if i could somewhere just tick "enable /function()-syntax in xPath" in sqlserver and the /concat(if...) would work)

Comment: `/text()` is not a function, even if it syntactically looks like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Books TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, BookInfo XML);

INSERT INTO @Books (BookInfo)
VALUES (N'<book>
    <title>a nice Novel</title>
    <author>Maria</author>
    <author>Peter</author>
</book>');

INSERT INTO @Books (BookInfo)
VALUES (N'<book>
    <title>another one</title>
    <author>Bob</author>
</book>');

SELECT *
FROM @Books bk
WHERE bk.BookInfo.exist('/book/author[text() = "Peter"]') = 1;
```

This returns only the first "book" entry. From there you can extract any portion of the XML field using the "value" function.

The "exist" function returns a boolean / BIT. This will scan through all "author" nodes within "book", so there is no need to concat into a comma-separated list only for use in an IN list, which wouldn't work anyway ;-).

For more info on the "value" and "exist" functions, as well as the other functions for use with XML data, please see:

[xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the solution, i added an explanation of my second constraint - as it now seems kind of vague to me too^^. What you propose would need some major changes, as the value is part of the expression and lacks an operator (see my edit). If you have any further ideas regarding this i beg your help - but your answer is something to consider the least, thanks again!

Comment: @billdoor : well, I looked at the updates to the question and they require more info. What are the possible values of `<operator>`? Is the string to search for (currently "Peter") also dynamic? It seems like you are looking for a dynamic WHERE clause.

Comment: operator can be any string ("=", "IN", "LIKE", anything really), "Peter" is the value in question, so dynamic too, yes

Comment: @billdoor : then this definitely requires dynamic SQL. What about conditions such as "Starts with" that equates to "LIKE param + N'%'", and "Ends with" that equates to "LIKE N'%' + param", and "Contains" that equates to "LIKE N'%' + param + N'%'"? Also, is the app passing the operator in?

Comment: the app passes in a SQL statement from an xml stucture that contains: the field (which evaluates to "expression"), the values and the operator. added an example to the question to make it clearer